# What's the circuitry inside triac driver optocouplers?

Tags: schematics, opto-isolator, triac

When looking through datasheets I can't find a single one that shows the inner circuit of a triac driver optocoupler, all I get is this common diagram:

[image]

What that zero crossing circuit looks like? how is it connected to the "triac"?
I'm specifically looking for details of this part [MOC3063M](https://www.onsemi.com/pdf/datasheet/moc3163m-d.pdf), but any description is appreciated.

Comment: http://lednique.com/opto-isolators-2/opto-triacs-zero-cross-work/

Comment: I have tested MOC3043M and it stops triggering the triac when V > 16V.

Comment: @G36 So it does have a snubber inside?

Comment: No, it does not have any snubber inside. This is just a example circuit.

Comment: @G36 How do you know that?

Comment: Because this schematic does not show the internal circuit of a MOC3063. Also in IC  large capacitors/resistors take a lot of space therefore they are avoided.

Comment: @G36 Don't say random values that came out of your specific IC, it is a range in the datasheet for a reason, each IC differs a tiny bit. The datasheet of a MOC3063M says 12V typ, 20V max, across the full temperature range of the product (with the voltage being lower at higher temperatures)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is a simple possibility that looks somewhat similar to @Tim's [die shot](https://zeptobars.com/en/read/MOC3061-Zero-cross-optoisolated-triac-driver-phototriac).

[image]

T1, T2, T1', T2' are the opto triac. aand T3/T3' shunt the gate current when the voltage is more than the zero crossing voltage.

[image]

Images are from [US 4,396,932](https://patentimages.storage.googleapis.com/cb/42/60/e9f736d5688c41/US4396932.pdf) 1983.

Obviously you cannot duplicate this circuit with ordinary discrete components because they could not withstand the required voltages (in particular Vgs(max) on T3/T3').

Comment: Isn't this better called anti-parallel SCRs, not a triac?

Comment: And, why aren't other companies doing this?  The patent is expired.

Comment: There are a number of companies making the ‘3041 type zero crossing optos. The ‘3063 is enhanced and may have some tricks that are still under patent. If you look at patents which reference the above one you should see various improvements which may or may not have made it to market. Whether the IC structure is portrayed for the user as a diac/triac or SBS, dual SCRs etc. is kind of a moot point. There is no gate, after all.

Comment: Really?  I can only find MOC3041 from Fairchild, which was later acquired by ON Semiconductor.  If it's beyond these two brand names, can you list some more parts  that you believe use this patent?

Comment: Isocom MOC3041X,  Everlight (Taiwan EL3041), Toshiba TLP266J, Sharp, QT, Panasonic, Vishay, Lite-on, and then there are the Chinese makers such as UMW, Cosmo, CT Micro (who have 800V rated parts such as CT3083). There are probably more.

Comment: Wow, I stand corrected (though maybe some use a different technique since the datasheets don't get into the details).  If there is an easy way for me to have found these replacement options, please explain it since my method of just searching Mouser for MOC3041 got me nothing.  Or maybe you are just familiar with all of these options by experimenting with them in the past...you are clearly a world-leading expert either way.

Answer (score 7):

The zero-crossing circuit *looks like* this:

[image: MOC3061 - Zero-cross optoisolated triac driver]

Source: [MOC3061 - Zero-cross optoisolated triac driver : weekend die-shot | Zeptobars](https://zeptobars.com/en/read/MOC3061-Zero-cross-optoisolated-triac-driver-phototriac) 
License: Creative Commons Attribution 3.0 Unported

It appears MOC3061-3 is a family, differing mainly in photosensitivity, which will depend on die and packaging variation, so likely they are identical parts (as fabbed), and labeled after testing; i.e. it isn't material that I'm answering a MOC3063 question with a -1.

As for what this means, that is a good question.  It's not clear to me where the bonding pads even should be, and there's no good reference for which layers are which, other than the shiny metal layer on top of course.  I would assume the substrate is n- doped, with epitaxial p- on top, then traditional microcircuitry on top of that.

An equivalent circuit comparable to that linked by G36, [Opto-triacs, solid-state relays (SSR), zero-cross and how they work](http://lednique.com/opto-isolators-2/opto-triacs-zero-cross-work/), certainly seems likely.

Comment: That's both the zero crossing circuit and the high voltage opto-triac, of course.

Comment: Yeah, I'm guessing something like, whereas a traditional TRIAC is three layers stacked plus diffusions on both sides, this is unfolded like opening a book, so, a two-layer substrate, and some circuitry on top. Circuitry which might not be at all functional while the thing is conducting, but, I mean, not like it has to be, hehe. Maybe it's even just a light diffusion, as seems likely given the example patent, and the apparent lack of mesa etch here.