Zero crossing on solid state relay, if power is applied
Theoretical question:
if a solid state relay has power on the control inputs, but the power for some reason is connected through a switch or relay, will the SSR conduct as soon as the switch is connected, or will it wait to the first (or a with a delay) zero crossing?

It depends on the type of SSR, I would imagine.

it may simply detect the power-off condition as a zero crossing

My (limited) understanding is that they will wait for the next zero-cross. The reasons why can be deduced from the schematic shown on my answer to https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/692762/73158 on this site (base on what I wrote LEDnique.com).
